# How to make multiple shots when there's just one camera?

Tags: shooting

I just want to have a Full shot at first and then a Medium full shot next in my video.

[image]

Is it possible if there's just one camera?

*My camera shoot on Full HD, and the video composition in the editing software is set on Full HD too, so it's not possible to scale the video to achieve the Medium shot out of the Full.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is basic film making, you would do this in multiple takes.

1. Take your wide shot running the whole scene you want with this shot
2. Take you scene back to the start point, adjust the camera to the new shot and run through the scene again
3. Rinse and repeat until you have all the shots needed to make your scene.

You would/should have already made a shot list knowing what needs to be shot with the different camera angles, sometimes only have to act parts of scenes over and over again to get the sections of the shots needed.

Other option would be to get a 4k/5k/6k camera and be able to punch in the shots during editing but this could cause further issues in post with file sizes, performaces, converting, encoding etc etc

Comment: So you mean if in my example if the man is going to say to the phone: "Hey...! How great the weather is today!", and I want the "Hey...! How great" in my Full shot and the "the weather is today!" in my Medium, I have to take this scene twice (the actor play it twice)?

Comment: According to the criteria of your question, yes, you do have to record your actors twice.  If you had a second camera, or a single, high-resolution camera, then you could record the scene in one take.

Comment: @Farzad This is a standard practice for filming multiple angles, for instance, if you were filming a scene in a cafe, I would probable film the scene 5/6 times from different angles and positions to edit down the scene in post. More cameras will give you more options but cost you more.